# How to pass a SQL query result to variable with VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I need to create a standalone function which checks whether a value is true or false. I have attempted to set up a SQL query that does this, but can't get the result to pass to the variable.

The query will always return only one record.

How can I pass the result of the SQL string as the returning value of the function?

UPDATED

```
Private Function HasBM(iMandate As Variant) As Boolean
'Returns boolean value for whether or not mandate has a benchmark
Dim sSQL1 As String
Dim sSQL2 As String

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

sSQL1 = "SELECT tbl_Mandate_Type.BM_Included " & _
        "FROM tbl_Mandate_Type INNER JOIN tbl_MoPo_BM ON tbl_Mandate_Type.Mandate_Type_ID = tbl_MoPo_BM.MandateType_ID " & _
        "WHERE (((tbl_MoPo_BM.MoPo_BM_ID)="

sSQL2 = "));"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.Execute(sSQL1 & iMandate & sSQL2)
HasBM = rs.Fields(0).Value

End Function
```

**UPDATE 2: SOLUTION**

Thanks for Magisch and HansUp I ended up getting two solutions that work:

**DLOOKUP Solution** by Magisch as I implemented it:

```
Private Function HasBM2(iMandate As Variant)
'Returns boolean value for whether or not mandate has a benchmark
Dim tmp As String

tmp = CStr(DLookup("tbl_MoPo_BM.MandateType_ID", "tbl_MoPo_BM", "tbl_MoPo_BM.MoPo_BM_ID = " & iMandate))
HasBM2 = DLookup("tbl_Mandate_Type.BM_Included", "tbl_Mandate_Type", "Mandate_Type_ID =" & tmp)

End Function
```

**Second Solution using recordset** as HansUp helped create:

```
Private Function HasBM(iMandate As Variant) As Boolean
'Returns boolean value for whether or not mandate has a benchmark
Dim sSQL1 As String
Dim sSQL2 As String

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As dao.Recordset

sSQL1 = "SELECT tbl_Mandate_Type.BM_Included " & _
        "FROM tbl_Mandate_Type INNER JOIN tbl_MoPo_BM ON tbl_Mandate_Type.Mandate_Type_ID = tbl_MoPo_BM.MandateType_ID " & _
        "WHERE (((tbl_MoPo_BM.MoPo_BM_ID)="

sSQL2 = "));"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL1 & iMandate & sSQL2)
HasBM = rs.Fields(0).Value

rs.close    

End Function
```

Comment: `DoCmd.RunSQL` is for action SQL only (insert, delete, update). To return results you'll need a recordset or something similar.

Comment: I was just exploring a similar solution... but still can't get it to work quite right.

Comment: Have you considered using the DLookup function?

Comment: I have considered the DLoopup function but since I need to join two tables to build the query I didn't think that would work. Please correct me if I'm wrong on that account.

Comment: you could use it twice

Comment: once to get the ID and once to get the value you want

Comment: am getting stuck on the `db.Execute` line. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: What does `Debug.Print sSQL1 & iMandate & sSQL2` show you?

Comment: @mielk do I need to change `rs` to be something other than recordset? `querydef` perhaps?

Comment: @HansUp I get the SQL String I need to run the query... it works fine if I just plug it into an empty new query... Actual result would be this: `SELECT tbl_Mandate_Type.BM_Included FROM tbl_Mandate_Type INNER JOIN tbl_MoPo_BM ON tbl_Mandate_Type.Mandate_Type_ID = tbl_MoPo_BM.MandateType_ID WHERE (((tbl_MoPo_BM.MoPo_BM_ID)=108));`

Comment: Then what did you mean when you said you are stuck at `db.Execute`?  Is there an error? Ack!  I think you need `OpenRecordset` instead of `Execute` there.

Comment: @hansup Sorry if that wasn't clear. The error is `Type Mismatch`

Comment: I just edited previous comment.  Does it work if you use `OpenRecordset`?

Comment: I posted a way using DLookup to get what you want

Comment: @HansUp no. I get the type mismatch if I run it using `recordset`

Comment: Declare the rs variable like this: `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset`  Does that eliminate the mismatch error?

Comment: @HansUp I just tested your solution as well. ALSO WORKS!

Comment: Wish I could award solution points to both you and Magisch. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the second solution, please do `rs.close` too to avoid memory leaks or other shenanigans.

Comment: @Magisch updated per your comment. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DLookup` function native to access for this. Since you have an `INNER JOIN` in your SQL, you will have to use it twice, but it'll still work.

Use a temporary string variable to store the temporary output, like this:

```
Dim tmp as String
tmp = Cstr(DLookup("tbl_MoPo_BM.MandateType_ID","tbl_MoPo_BM","tbl_MoPo_BM.MoPo_BM_ID = " & iMandate)) 'This is to fetch the ID you performed the inner join on
HasBM = DLookup("tbl_Mandate_Type.BM_Included","tbl_Mandate_Type","Mandate_Type_ID =" & tmp) ' this is to get your value
```

Using your `DoCmd.RunSQL` will not suffice since its for action queries only (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`) and incapable of returning the result.

Alternatively, you can use a Recordset with your SQL query to fetch what you want, but thats more work and the DLookup is designed to exactly avoid doing that for single column return selects.

Comment: @rohrl77 the idea is (typos notwithstanding) to use the DLookup first to fetch the ID you INNER JOINed on, and then use that ID to fetch the proper value.

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Thank you... I'll post the final solution code above for future refrence

Comment: @rohrl77 please also leave the error code above so people can reference the problem.